# hosting multiple websites on multiple servers with a single outside IP address

Tags: web-server, proxy, redirection

I have a single outside, static IP address. I have a domain registered (abc123xyz.com) that points to this IP address. I would like to be able to set up multiple servers (Microsoft and Linux) on the inside of my network that are available as subdomains. For example, if someone browses to s1.abc123xyz.com, they'll go to a website that is hosted on my internal server1. s2.abc123xyz.com will go to a website hosted on server2, and so on. I'm not talking about virtual hosts because virtual hosts are on a single server. I'm talking about sites on separate servers.

I'd like to forward web traffic to a single inside IP and then control the redirection from that device. Is this what a (reverse) proxy server would be used for?

Comment: In a word: Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly. You need one http endpoint that takes the requests and then forwards the requests to the appropiate server on the inside. This is the very definition of a reverse proxy.

Note that this means you need to introduce either specialized hardware (i.e. a more capable router or firewall appliance), OR you use one of your backend computers. Instead of having

Reverse proxy -> server W and L

you could have

Server W -> forwarding specific domains to Server L